# How to remove ld: duplicate symbol _ in xcode 4.2 ( c++ code )

Tags: c++, ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to compile the c++ code in xcode and I am getting following error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _selectedFields in Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadHeaderTBL-arftrodtnbtmucbjkejinzonhulu/Build/Intermediates/ReadHeaderTBL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadHeaderTBL.build/Objects-normal/i386/readingTBLCPP.o and /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadHeaderTBL-arftrodtnbtmucbjkejinzonhulu/Build/Intermediates/ReadHeaderTBL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadHeaderTBL.build/Objects-normal/i386/ReadFile.o for architecture i386
```

The symbol " `selectedFields` " is declared in one class and invoked from other.

It is declared as:

```
       std::string selectedFields;
```

I  am not getting the cause for this error.

Comment: where and how exactly do you declare your variable?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when we get this problem it's because people have declared the variable in a header file. You should *define* it in a header file

```
extern std::string selectedFields; // definition
```

and declare it in *one* source file

```
std::string selectedFields; // declaration
```

If your problem is something else then *post the code*. It gets a bit dispiriting to have to guess what everyone's problem is because they don't bother to post code.